# Create a project outside localhost and use your own alias

Tags: xampp, localhost, alias

1.Open Xampp Control Panel

2.Right-click the Apache Config button and choose 'httpd-xampp.conf'

[xampp detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENwNR.png)

3.Scroll to the bottom of the file.
[file detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRiMo.png)

4.Add this code; the alias can change based on your preference, and the path is the specified path.

```
Alias /basicv2 "C:/xampp/htdocs/basicv2/basic/web"
        <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/basicv2/basic/web">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
            #Options FollowSymLinks
            #Order allow,deny
            #Allow from all
        </Directory>
```

5.Close XAMPP, reopen it, and then try running the port using localhost/basicv2.

This is how to create a project outside localhost and use your own alias